How to select Aurora PostgreSQL Instance Class type
we are migrating from Oracle on premise to AWS Aurora PostgreSQL(Global), Its for ecommerce mission critical application. We have below configuration in Oracle Database.



parameter
value




Max no of processes
1500


Max no of session
2500


RAM
96 GB


VCPU
112


Storage
300 GB



We decided to make use of Memory optimized instance class type. But we are not sure which instance class type (db.r5.large,db.r6.large..etc), which one would be better for above configuration and how to decide that?

I wouldn't use a public cloud for a mission critical database.

Only you can determine which Instance Type to use, since it depends on how you use your database. It's basically a trade-off between RAM, CPU and cost, with the benefit that you can change the Instance Type at any time (it will require a restart of the database). So, pick something and monitor it for a while. If you run short of resources, make it bigger. If it's too expensive, then make it smaller. If it's critical, then make sure you understand how to use PostgreSQL (which is different to Oracle) and how to take advantage of Aurora's capabilities.

There's also the possibility of a serverless option but any such decision depends on what load you're putting on it? Is it read-heavy or write-heavy? Short-running queries or long-running reports? Spiky load or consistent-ish? Also take a look at https://instances.vantage.sh/
